# How to implement a timed loop?

Tags: c, embedded-linux

I need to execute some code 1000 times per second.
I would like to do something like:

```
set up interval timer
while (1)
{
   wait for timer
   do something
}
```

My attempt looks like

```
// Create timer
timer_t timerid;
struct sigevent sev;

sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
sev.sigev_signo = SIGUSR1;

if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &timerid))
{
perror("timer_create");
exit(1);
}

// Every one mSec (10^6 nsec)
struct itimerspec its;
its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
its.it_value.tv_nsec = 1000000;
its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 1000000;
if (timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL))
{
perror("timer_settime");
exit(1);
}

// Create mask to wait for SIGUSR1
sigset_t set;
sigemptyset(&set);
sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);

while (1)
{
int sig;

// Wait for the timer: Do this loop once per millisecond
sigwait(&set, &sig);

    (do something)
}
```

When I try this, I just get "User defined signal 1" at the console and my program exits. This is not surprising, as this is the default action for the signal. If I set the signal to SIG_IGN using sigaction(2), I never get to my (do something).

I presume I need to do something with sigaction(2), but I don't see an option for "deliver the signal". I don't want to ignore the signal, or do the default action, or call a function.
What's the best way to accomplish my goal?

Or I can just give up and put my (do something) in a function :-)

Edit: I implemented the timerfd idea, and it seems to be working. On to the next bug...

Comment: Why not simply `nanosleep` for the appropriate interval? Note that you need to calculate the interval yourself based on the next timestamp when the action needs to execute, and the current time. (If you always wait for 1ms between iterations, you will execute less than 1000 iterations per seconds, exactly how many depending on the time it takes to "do something".)

Comment: There is a rather large set of possible actions beside SIG_IGN.

Comment: @n.m "There is a rather large set of possible actions beside SIG_IGN." Quoting from http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html: sa_handler specifies the action to be associated with signum and may
       be SIG_DFL for the default action, SIG_IGN to ignore this signal, or
       a pointer to a signal handling function. What other options are available?

Comment: "a pointer to a signal-handling function" is an element of a very large set.

Comment: Sorry, I was counting a function pointer as one option, primarily because it did not seem to satisfy my preferred way of solving my problem. I think there is a hole, either in my understanding of signals, or in their implementation, if my code fragment above can not be made to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have tagged your question with `embedded-linux` I assume that portability is not an issue. In that case you might want to have a look at [timerfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html). It will allow you to use `select(2)`/`poll(2)` to receive your timer events. It will also make it easier to combine the interval timer with other event sources such as file descriptors.

Comment: +1 for using timerfd. That way your program will still work even if you link to a library that uses SIGUSR1 for something library internal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set a true signal handler as suggested by n.m. Look at `man sigaction` for your version of Linux. You can either call your `do_something` in signal handler (and wait for something else for program termination) or have a return only handler and keep you sigwait logic.